# CodeIgniter File Upload overwrite FALSE (default) auto-rename issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

There is an error message in CodeIgniter

> The file name you submitted already exists on the server

Does that make any sense? Let me explain.

There is a preference in [File Uploading Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) preferences called "overwrite". It can be TRUE or FALSE. The default value is FALSE. If it's TRUE, then the file will be overwritten. If it's FALSE, then a number will be appended to the filename if another with the same name exists. So, either it'll overwrite the file or it will rename the file. How is it possible to get the above error?

So, it looks like CodeIgniter is unable to rename the files properly.

I looked at my database and found how CodeIgniter has renamed the files. Though there are no other file exists with the same name, some of the filenames are appended an underscore ( _ ), but no number after that. I also found that when I tried to upload a file with file name as "myfilename.zip" several times, "myfilename_.zip", "myfilename_1.zip", "myfilename_2.zip" ... "myfilename_11.zip" found at the upload path. But "myfilename.zip" is not found there and instead of creating "myfilename_12.zip", it showed me the above error.

So, where is the issue? How to solve this?

**Update:**
Now I understood why I am getting the error message `The file name you submitted already exists on the server`. The mechanism to check whether any file with the same name exists work for 100 files. It checks whether any file with the same name exists, if found, then it appends a number to filename and check again. This happens 100 times. If still a file with the same name found, it stops, so that the execution of the script will not take much time. So, we can say there is a limit and 100 is a good limit.

But I am still looking for the answer, why some files are appended an underscore, some with an underscore and then a number, and some with just the number. There is no consistency with the pattern to append a number to the files, if another file with the same name exists.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by setting `$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE`.

Comment: where u added this ?

Answer (score 0):

you have not put your code here.However, I think you have set your file name to a fixed one using [file_name] index and have put an constraint on it.

Comment: I did not put my code here, as I am using the basic code. I have not set the filename using [file_name] index, so that the original filename can be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

> I looked at my database and found how CodeIgniter has renamed the
>   files. Though there are no other file exists with the same name, some
>   of the filenames are appended an underscore ( _ ), but no number after
>   that

It's happening because by default the option below changes spaces to underscores ... Change it to FALSE if you want to keep spaces.

```
remove_spaces   TRUE
```

Regarding your `"The file name you submitted already exists on the server"` message -
you will have to do something like ...

```
if($_FILES['image']['error'] == 0){
   $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
   if(file_exists($upload_dir.$file_name)) {
      show_error('The file name you submitted already exists on the server!');
   } else {
      //do_upload() etc
   }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but it should give you some ideas.

Comment: There is no space in the filenames. So, I don't understand the logic to rename filename.zip to filename_.zip after upload.

In my case, I have not set "overwrite" preference to anything. So, the default value is FALSE. So, the File Uploading Class of CodeIgniter should rename the files by appending a number after the filename and save it, if another file with the same name exists. This is not working fine for me.

I don't need to use any code, as you suggested, because File Uploading Class of CodeIgniter handles those. What I am worried about is the reason to get the error message.